# SQL Server - Get sum subtracted by previous row's sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a query which returns number of requests to different objects sampled by date,
there can be more than one sampler per day.
the With part at the beginning is used for getting only the latest sample each day.

```
With RankedSamples As
    (
    Select  Id, runend
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY convert(varchar , runEnd, 1) ORDER BY runEnd DESC ) ItemRank
    From t_SamplesRuns
    where runend > '05/13/12' and runend < '05/18/12'
    )

select sum(TotalRequests) Hits, 
       convert(nvarchar(10), day(smp.date)) + '-' + 
       convert(nvarchar(10), month(smp.date)) + '-' + 
       convert(nvarchar(10), year(smp.date)) date
from t_samples smp
where  smp.runid in (                 
    select id                 
    from RankedSamples                 
    where ItemRank = 1  
    )    

group by convert(nvarchar(10), day(smp.date)) + '-' + 
         convert(nvarchar(10), month(smp.date)) + '-' + 
         convert(nvarchar(10), year(smp.date))
```

what this returns is for example:

```
Hits     date
111111   13-5-2012
222222   14-5-2012
333333   15-5-2012
444444   16-5-2012
555555   17-5-2012
```

what I need it to return is these fields + the number of hits from the day before and their subtraction  (first row irelevant) :

```
Hits     date       Prev     Res
111111   13-5-2012  0        111111
222223   14-5-2012  111111   111112
333335   15-5-2012  222223   111113 
444447   16-5-2012  333335   111114
555559   17-5-2012  444447   111115
```

any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using SQL Server 2012, what you are trying to do is implement a lag function.  Unfortunately, the easiest way to do this is with a self join.  So, I'm going to rewrite your query to do this:

```
With RankedSamples As (
      Select Id, runend,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY convert(varchar , runEnd, 1) ORDER BY runEnd DESC) as ItemRank
      From t_SamplesRuns
      where runend > '05/13/12' and runend < '05/18/12'
    )
     Results as (
      select sum(TotalRequests) Hits,
             convert(nvarchar(10), day(smp.date)) + '-' +  convert(nvarchar(10), month(smp.date)) + '-' +         convert(nvarchar(10), year(smp.date)) as date
      from t_samples smp where  smp.runid in (select id from RankedSamples where ItemRank = 1)
      group by convert(nvarchar(10), day(smp.date)) + '-' +  convert(nvarchar(10), month(smp.date)) + '-' +  convert(nvarchar(10), year(smp.date)
    ),
     Results2 as (
         select r.*, row_number() over (partition by null order by date) as rownum
         from Results
    )
select r.hits, r.date, rprev.hits, r.hits - rprev.hits
from Results2 r left outer join
     Results2 rprev
     on r.rownum = rprev.rownum+1
```

As I said, this is easier in SQL Server 2012, because the window functions are more similar to Oracles analytic functions.